# Editing Postgresql GUC parameters

Tags: postgresql, module

I am trying to use the [pg_trgm module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) in my database. This module has a "similarity threshold" GUC parameter that I want to edit. This is easy to accomplish using the `set_limit()` function, but that function is deprecated.

From what I understand the correct way to do it is to either edit the GUC parameter manually, or edit it using `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold()`.

I have been unable to locate the parameter to edit manually, and all my attempts at using `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold()` have led to syntax errors.

How does one edit Postgresql GUC parameters?

Comment: Please provide more information about what you've tried, some code examples, your error example, etc.

Comment: Here's an example: SELECT pg_trgm.similarity_threshold(0.4); which gives ERROR schema not found.Here's another one: SELECT similarity_threshold(0.4); which gives ERROR function does not exist. I've tried some other variations but you get the jist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GUC parameters are stored in [`postgresql.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html).

As the parameters for the pgtrgm extension are non-standard, they are not part of a standard `postgresq.conf` file.

You need to add those parameters manually to the file.

Typically this is done after the comment "Add settings for extensions here" add the end of the file, e.g.:

```
# CUSTOMIZED OPTIONS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Add settings for extensions here
pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.5
pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold = 0.5
```

Instead of editing the file, you can also use [`alter database`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdatabase.html) or [`alter system`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersystem.html) to change those values. In that case those values will be added to the `postgresql.auto.conf` file automatically.

Comment: I forgot to mention this in the original post, but the parameter is not present in the postgresql.conf file.

Comment: @guest856: then add it (which is done automatically with the `ALTER` statements)

Comment: How do I get the current value of these parameters? Just like there is an ALTER statement, is there a way to query them?

Comment: @RobinJonsson [show](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-show.html) or [current_setting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET)